# Pip install gives "no free space"

Tags: linux, python, pip

I'm new to linux, and I'm trying to install a package (more than 700MB) using pip install. However, as I run the following command

```
pip install torch==1.8.0
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

I've done my googling online but none of them worked for me. Examples are:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir torch==1.8.0

TMPDIR=~/data/vincents/ pip install --cache-dir=~/data/vincents/ --build ~/data/vincents/ torch==1.8.0
```

Furthermore, I do not understand any of these solutions.

Here's my system free space (I'm using a Google Cloud Compute instance):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  9.0M  1.5G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       194G  194G  702M 100% /
tmpfs           7.4G  648K  7.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      504M  504M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/242
/dev/loop2      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/10958
/dev/loop3      504M  504M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/240
/dev/loop1       99M   99M     0 100% /snap/core/11081
tmpfs           1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /run/user/1001
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Where is `~/data/vincents/`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's a solution I found online, which includes the username of the person who posted it. `~` is my home directory, and `/data/vincents` is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: Are you not aware `/` is pretty much full or are you having problem in resizing the partition and filesystem?

Comment: I didn't know how to read the output. You are reading from `Mounted on` column, right?

Comment: You must free up space for the operating system to “breathe”. I suggest looking into `virtualenv` to create localized Python environments.

Comment: Also, in case you’re wondering which line of `df` to check, you can explicitly run it against a path: `df -h ~/data/vincents/`. It will then output information relevant to this path.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks! I checked using `df -h ~` and immediately noticed the lack of space. I then deleted some files and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5816#issuecomment-425205365)

```
TMPDIR=/data/vincents/ pip install --cache-dir=/data/vincents/ --build /data/vincents/ tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

```
TMPDIR=/mybigtemp pip3 --cache-dir /mybigtemp  install tensorflow tensorflow_probability
```

This works for Python 3.9 and pip 23.1. You need to set the variable `TMPDIR` and additionally you need to specify the `--cache-dir` option. See all pip install options in the help:

```
pip3 help install
```